# Creating Report in access based on Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Good day

I'm creating a report based on 7 Query's
 the 1st query gets product_name
 the 2nd query gets sub_product_name
 the 3rd query gets sub_sub_product_name .... and so on

Not all products drop-down 7 levels, Thus only 3 query's are in use,
ie(the other query's are blank, 'Which is what it is supposed to do)

How do I create a report based on only the Query's that are in use,
Is there a way to check ...if query.field is null create reportA
or something similar

A QUESTION derived on prev Question "Repitition of Query to produce report"
{[Repetition of query to produce report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393626/repitition-of-query-to-produce-report/1403721#1403721)}

Thanks

Comment: Adding ms-access to your tags will greatly increase your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard Bill of Materials question.  See [Modules: Bill Of Materials](http://www.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0027.htm) for one approach.  I'm sure there are many other approaches.